# Does this refer to 'to reward inventors~'?

Tags: pronouns, antecedents

Or, does it refer to 'the original rationale for granting patents'?

> Patents and copyright laws grant too much credit and reward to
> individuals and imply that technology evolves by jerks. Recall that
> the original rationale for granting patents was not to reward
> inventors with monopoly profits but to encourage them to share their
> inventions. A certain amount of intellectual property law is plainly
> necessary to achieve ***this***. But it has gone too far. Mostpatents
> are now as much about defending monopoly and deterring rivals asabout
> sharing ideas. And that discourages innovation.

[The Myth of Basic Science- WSJ](https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-myth-of-basic-science-1445613954)

Comment: “This” refers to “the original rationale” as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

> Recall that the original rationale for granting patents was not to reward inventors with monopoly profits but to encourage them to share their inventions.

The goal stated here, which *achieve* can work with, is "encouraging them to share their inventions."  So that is what the *this* has to point back to.

- "The original rationale for granting patents" can't be a goal because we don't know what that is until it's defined later in the sentence.
- "To reward inventors with monopoly profits" is negated by "not" and also the following "but" so it's specifically not the goal.